# Nhibernate Multiple table have One to many relation to specific table

Tags: c#, sql, .net, nhibernate

I have a table let's call A.
A has the field - objId.

There are other tables let's call B, C and D. that have a list of A records.
A record need to be craeted by adding A record to the list of A records of one of the tables B, C and D. A objId field need to be the PK (id) of the B/C/D record Who has the list of A.

which meant - objId is  FK to many table.
I begin with table B.
But after B table created the field objId of table A created. and now what will be with thae table C and D? They can't create agian the column objId in a table.

The code is:

```
<id name="Id">
  <generator class="guid" />
</id>

<bag name="As" cascade="All">
  <key column="ObjId" />
  <one-to-many class="A" />
</bag>
```

```
<class name="A">
<id name="Id">
  <generator class="guid" />
</id>
<property name="ObjId" />
```

```
public class B
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<A> As{ get; set; }
}

public class A
{  
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string ObjId { get; set; }
}
```

adding  A record to B:

```
       this.Update(session =>
       {
           var bRecord = ....;

           bRecord.As.Add(new ARecord {
                 ...
          });

             session.Update(bRecord);
       });
```

How need I to create right the assosiacion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are, in general, more ways how to handle this scenario - each of them will require some adjustments/extending. I.e. you must change your DB structure anyway

If the instance of the *A* could be referenced by each of the B, C, D  the only way would be to introduce foreign key columns BObjectId, CObjectId, DObjectId.

If the instance of the A can be exclusively used by one of them (B, C, D) we would need new column, let's call it `Discriminator`

```
<class name="A">
  <id name="Id" generator="guid" />
 <property name="ObjId" />
 <property name="Discriminator" />
</class>
```

Now, we have to correctly fill in the value into Discriminator in our C# Code. If A is assigned to B, we have to fill in 'B'

```
var a = new A();
b.AddA(a);
```

where the implementation should be like this.

```
public virtual void AddA(A a)
{
    As.Add(a);
    a.ObjectId = this.ID
    a.Discriminator = 'B'
}
```

*NOTE: in this case, we assign the ID into `ObjectId`. It is working, but only if the ID is already assigned. It won't work if the object `B` is transient, with default ID value. In that case we will need to create some workaround. E.g. Flush() the B and then assign the reference...*

So, we succeeded to correctly manage/fill-in/insert the Discriminator value into the A instance/record. Now we can use it also for **mapping**. The B, C, D bag-mapping will be very similar:

```
<class name="A">
  <bag name="As" cascade="All" batch-size="25"
    where=" Discriminator = 'B' " >
      <key column="ObjId" />
      <one-to-many class="A" />
  </bag>
```

The `where=" Discriminator = 'B' "` is the NHibernate nice way how to inject the filter into our collection. Apply the same for C, D... and ...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. As you say- 'There are, in general, more ways how to handle this scenario'. what are they? Is the way you wrote is the best way?

Comment: Great if that helped anyhow. Enjoy NHiberante ;)